# Dynamic creation of pages using Apex 4.2

Tags: html, plsql, oracle-apex

I want to build an application in Apex V4.2 (similar to online exams), which will have one question per page with multiple choice answers. Both questions and answers will be stored in Oracle database. The number of questions may vary from time to time and even the ordering, so, I want the page creation to be dynamic. How to create pages dynamically in Apex or if that is not possible is there a option of changing/refreshing the content of the page on a button click.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Don't think of how to create additional pages - think how to make one page that, given the ID for a question, knows how to present that question.

You'll need a data model that stores the information about which questions should be asked and in what order. Add a "Next" button on the page which works out what the next question should be and navigates back to the same page with the new Question ID.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show a question and a set of answers on one page rather than to create pages dynamically. Look on task from this point of view.

In APEX a simple skeleton of solution for your task could consist of one page with three items. First item is Display Only item (saves session state), based on LOV, for storing an answer ID; second one is Radiobutton for single choice answers; third one is Checkbox for answers with multiple choice. Last two items should use a LOV, which relates on the first item value.

Add to this sceleton the buttons to navigate back and forth through the answers of an exam, to submit a choice; the processes to save submitted choices, to query current, next and previous questions; the branches for navigation -- and it will be your app.

Good luck.